# how to draw two boxes side by side in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

I want to draw two boxes with text inside, side by side in one "tikzpicture", since I'm a newbie in tikz, I managed to do this(MWE), could you please help me to achieve it, I would be grateful.

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (example-align) [draw,very thick, align=left,text width=7.5em]{Machine \\ \hspace{0.4cm} variables \\\hspace{0.4cm} invariants \\\hspace{0.4cm} theorems \\\hspace{0.4cm} variant \\\hspace{0.4cm} events}; &
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \hspace{1.4cm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (example-align) [draw,very thick, align=left,text width=7.5em] {Context \\ \hspace{0.4cm} carrier sets  \\\hspace{0.4cm} constants \\\hspace{0.4cm} axioms \\ \hspace{0.4cm} theorems};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Surely that code gives you an error?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer that's what I want to do when I put two \node in one tikzpicture I get two nodes in the same place.

Comment: @cfr I get this error : Misplaced alignment tab character &. ...{0.4cm} variant \\\hspace{0.4cm} events}; &

Comment: That's because you have an `&` for reasons I fail to understand. Was it meant to be there? If code you're posting produces an error, you should be asking how to avoid it and include the text of the error message. If you know how to avoid it, then it makes no sense to post code which produces it.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That is the OP's question, in fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one possibility as one `tikzpicture` which contain two boxes:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% for positioning of nodes

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 0mm and 12mm,% for distance between nodes
   box/.style = {draw, very thick, minimum width=5em}% nodes style
                        ]
\node (n1) [box] {\begin{tabular}{ll}% text in nodes write as table
                  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Machine}   \\
                  & variables                   \\
                  & invariants                  \\
                  & theorems                    \\
                  & variant                     \\
                  & events
                 \end{tabular}};
\node (n2) [box, below right=of n1.north east]
                {\begin{tabular}{ll}
                  \multicolumn{2}{l}{Context}   \\
                  & carrier sets                \\
                  & constants                   \\
                  & axioms                      \\
                  & theorems
                 \end{tabular}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct is spot on: to put the two nodes in one picture. Fortunately, this is quite straightforward.

I would use the `positioning` library to position the second node relative to the first. I would also use `enumitem` to create a custom list environment rather than manually inserting spaces at the start of each line after the first.

For example,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, enumitem}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newlist{myalign}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[myalign]{label=,leftmargin=4mm,labelwidth=*,nosep}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    my text node/.style={draw, very thick, align=left, text width=7.5em}
  ]
  \node (example-align) [my text node] {Machine\\\begin{myalign} \item variables \item invariants \item theorems \item variant \item events\end{myalign}};
  \node (example-align2) [my text node, right=1.4cm of example-align.north east, anchor=north west] {Context\\\begin{myalign} \item carrier sets  \item constants \item axioms \item theorems\end{myalign}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I've aligned the lists at the top by using `north east` and `north west` as anchors. If you wanted them bottom aligned, you could use `south east` and `south west` or, for vertical centring, either specify no anchors or use just `east` and `west`.

[image: aligned lists]