# Two side by side flowchart (tikz-flowchart) with box and label for each

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-pic

I need to draw two flowchart using TikZ with a box around each flowchart and a label. I'm new to Tikz library and I have looked similar questions regarding pictures and tables and figures. They suggest to use `minipage` or `scope` or `Figure`. I tried to use them but it seems I'm missing something. I found an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392391/how-to-draw-two-boxes-side-by-side-in-tikz) posted by @[crf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr), which suggesting using `positioning` tikzlibrary. I couldn't figure out what's I'm missing.

Here is what I have done:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % define shapes % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\tikzstyle{block}    = [rectangle, rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, 
 minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5cm]
\tikzstyle{cloud}    = [rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, minimum 
 height=1cm, text centered, draw, ellipse,fill=blue!20, text width=2cm]
 \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
 % % % % % %  1st Chart    % %%  % % %   
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
 %\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =5mm and 8mm ]
%\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=-1.2,line width=1pt]
 % Place nodes
\node [block] (init) {Process1 and long description };
\node [cloud, above =of init] (input1) {Input1};
\node [cloud, left= of init] (input2) {Input2};
\node [block, below= of init] (Process2) {Process 2 and description};
\node [block, below=of Process2] (Process3) {Process 3 and description};
\node [block, below =of Process3] (Process4) {Process 4  and description};
% Draw edges
\path [line] (init) -- (Process2);
\path [line] (Process2) -- (Process3);
\path [line] (Process3) -- (Process4);
\path [line,dashed] (input1) -- (init);
\path [line,dashed] (input2) -- (init);
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{minipage}
\qquad
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
 % % % % % %  2nd Chart  % % %  % %% %   
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%\begin{minipage}[b][1cm][s]{.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture} [node distance = 5mm and 8mm] 
 %[scale=0.2,line width=1pt]
% \begin{scope}[shift={(1,5)}]
 % Place nodes
 \node [block] (init) {Process1 Flow 2 };
 \node [block, below= of init,  node distance=0.5mm] (Process2F2) {Process2 
  Flow 2};
 \node [cloud, left= of Process2F2,node distance=1cm] (input1f2) {input 1 
  flow 2 };
 \node [block, below= of Process2F2,  node distance=0.5mm] (Process3F2) 
  {Process3 Flow 2};
  \node [cloud, right= of Process3F2,node distance=1cm] (input2f2) {input 2 
  Flow 2};
 \node [block, below=of Process3F2,node distance=1cm] (Process4F2) {Process4 
 Flow 2};
 % Draw edges
 \path [line] (init) -- (Process2F2);
 \path [line] (Process2F2) -- (Process3F2);
 \path [line] (Process3F2) -- (Process4F2);
 \path [line,dashed] (input2f2) -- (Process3F2);
 \path [line,dashed] (input1f2) -- (Process2F2);
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %   
 % % % box to contain each chart % %
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %  
\draw [color=gray,thick](-7,-9) rectangle (7,4);
\node at (-1.8,-9.5) [below=2cm, right=10mm] {  \textbf{flow 2 label} };
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %      
%\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I need to have two boxes side by side and label for each box. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is straightforward to add a frame around the flow charts but the issue is that they are too wide to be shown side by side. BTW, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, use `\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, 
 minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5cm},
cloud/.style={rounded corners,  minimum width=3cm, minimum 
 height=1cm, text centered, draw, ellipse,fill=blue!20, text width=2cm},
line/.style={draw, -latex'}}` instead.

Comment: Thanks marmot. Any idea to change the width of the flow charts to fit side by side?.

Comment: Adding some text width to the bulky nodes (e.g. `text width=1cm`) such that their texts will be in multiple lines, decreasing their `minimum widths`, `inner xsep` and `node distance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick proposal which I will be happy to delete.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning}
\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\centering
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % define shapes % % % % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\tikzset{block/.style={rectangle, rounded corners,  text width=1.5cm, 
 minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw, fill=blue!20},
cloud/.style={rounded corners, inner sep=-4pt,  minimum 
 height=1cm, text centered, draw, ellipse,fill=blue!20, text width=2cm},
line/.style={draw, -latex'}}%
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
 % % % % % %  1st Chart    % %%  % % %   
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
 %\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =5mm and 4mm ]
%\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=-1.2,line width=1pt]
 % Place nodes
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=left]
 \node [block] (init) {Process1 and long description };
 \node [cloud, above =of init] (input1) {Input1};
 \node [cloud, left= of init] (input2) {Input2};
 \node [block, below= of init] (Process2) {Process 2 and description};
 \node [block, below=of Process2] (Process3) {Process 3 and description};
 \node [block, below =of Process3] (Process4) {Process 4  and description};
 % Draw edges
 \path [line] (init) -- (Process2);
 \path [line] (Process2) -- (Process3);
 \path [line] (Process3) -- (Process4);
 \path [line,dashed] (input1) -- (init);
 \path [line,dashed] (input2) -- (init);
\end{scope}
\draw[color=gray,thick](left.south west) rectangle (left.north east);
\node[anchor=north,font=\bfseries] at ([yshift=-2em]left.south) {flow 1 label};

 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
 % % % % % %  2nd Chart  % % %  % %% %   
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
%\begin{minipage}[b][1cm][s]{.15\textwidth}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=right,xshift=6cm] 
 %[scale=0.2,line width=1pt]
% \begin{scope}[shift={(1,5)}]
 % Place nodes
 \node [block] (init) {Process1 Flow 2 };
 \node [block, below= of init,  node distance=0.5mm] (Process2F2) {Process2 
  Flow 2};
 \node [cloud, left= of Process2F2,node distance=1cm] (input1f2) {input 1 
  flow 2 };
 \node [block, below= of Process2F2,  node distance=0.5mm] (Process3F2) 
  {Process3 Flow 2};
  \node [cloud, right= of Process3F2,node distance=1cm] (input2f2) {input 2 
  Flow 2};
 \node [block, below=of Process3F2,node distance=1cm] (Process4F2) {Process4 
 Flow 2};
 % Draw edges
 \path [line] (init) -- (Process2F2);
 \path [line] (Process2F2) -- (Process3F2);
 \path [line] (Process3F2) -- (Process4F2);
 \path [line,dashed] (input2f2) -- (Process3F2);
 \path [line,dashed] (input1f2) -- (Process2F2);
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %   
 % % % box to contain each chart % %
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %  
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %      
\end{scope}
\draw[color=gray,thick](right.south west) rectangle (right.north east);
\node[anchor=north,font=\bfseries] at ([yshift=-2em]right.south) {flow 2 label};
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`shoframe` is only added to show that it fits.